# Fastest and lightest way to get the current time in milliseconds with JS Date object

Tags: javascript, performance, date

There are different ways to get the current time in milliseconds with `Date` object:

```
(new Date()).getTime();
+new Date();
Date.now();
```

Assuming that you don't need to create an object and just need a current time in milliseconds, which one would be the most effective one? In terms of performance.

EDIT: I understand most devs wouldn't care about this, but it may matter when you work in a low-tech embedded environment or just to kill the curiosity.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because micro-optimisation is boring

Comment: I guess `Date.now();` as it (probably) doesn't create a new Data object instance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about codereview (kind of).

Comment: Can someone please explain the
+new Date()
or
+new Date

Comment: @vanowm `Date` object is directly converted to a number with [the unary plus (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Date.now()` wins.  See [jsPerf test](https://jsperf.app/nimime).

But as noted in comments above, the CPU cost is likely uninteresting compared to just about anything else you'll be doing.

@techfoobar mentions the cost of allocating `Date` objects (or, really, the cost of *garbage collecting* those `Date` objects). That may or may not be a significant win, as `Date.now()` is probably allocating numbers, which would be about as expensive.

Comment: Number objects? Why? It's number literals.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if the timestamp is obtained for anything other than timestamping the data, for example, the timing of code execution, it is always a good idea to think if the same can be achieved via setTimeout or setInterval calls instead, without direct access to timestamp value.

Answer (score 0):

Since performance.now() has not been discussed here, and since jsperf.com seems to be down right now, I have done a few simple tests, which show that the ranking of fastness is:

1. Date.now() -- about 1 second for 10 million iterations
2. new Date() -- about 2 seconds for 10 million iterations
3. performance.now() -- about 4 seconds for 10 million iterations

sadly, performance.now() appears 4 times slower than Date.now(). That is on Chrome.

Here is my code, upgrading to 100 million iterations, and there the performance.new() test is getting even worse. And don't worry that I used performance.now() as the measurement timer for all 3 options, what matters is what's in the loop. I did 100 million iterations for my last test because I wanted to see if garbage collection on new Date() and Date.now() might kick in and come to penalize us. But no, what got worse is not them but the performance.now() method.

```
function perftest(iterations, fn) {
    const start = performance.now();
    for(let i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        fn();
    return performance.now() - start;
}

> perftest(100000000, () => Date.now())
< 11285.5
> perftest(100000000, () => new Date())
< 22834.59999999404
> perftest(100000000, () => performance.now())
< 48602.40000000596
```

By the way, the indirection through the fn() function call is really really tiny. It adds about 200 ms to the total compared to calling the test statement directly in the loop.

Comment: Sorry for downvoting, but: 1) [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) doesn't measure the same thing as `Date.now()`, and 2) jsPerf had been "[reincarnated](https://jsperf.app/nimime)"